# Insert into xml in sql using modify method

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have to modify the existing xml in a table field value.
Each row value has different xml tags  like

1 row.
`'<root><comments><comment>comments1</comment><comment>comments2</comment></comments></root>'`

2 row .

```
'<Users><User><Name>MAK</Name></User><User><Name>DANNY</User></Users>'
```

I need to add a tag `<Resource>some ID</Resource>` 
after the root node.

like `'<Users>**<Resource>some ID</Resource>**<User><Name>comments1</Name></User><User><Name>comments2</User></Users>'`

I have tried with the below code .

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<root><comments><comment>comments1</comment><comment>comments2</comment></comments></root>'
declare @Note varchar(10)
declare @insertnode nvarchar(100)
set @insertnode='commeressd'
declare @mainnode varchar(50)
set @mainnode='(//root)[1]'
set @Note = 'comment3'
SET @xml.modify('insert <Resource>{xs:string(sql:variable("@insertnode"))}</Resource> as first into {xs:string(sql:variable("@mainnode"))}')
select @xml
```

the expression after

> into

is giving the error

> XQuery [modify()]: Syntax error near '{'

..how do we specify this into expression also dynamically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `/*[1]` to find the "first" root node where you want the insert to happen.

```sql
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '
<root>
  <comments>
    <comment>comments1</comment>
    <comment>comments2</comment>
  </comments>
</root>'

declare @insertnode nvarchar(100)

set @insertnode='ResourceID'

set @xml.modify('insert element Resource {sql:variable("@insertnode")} as first into /*[1]')

select @xml
```

Result:

```xml
<root>
  <Resource>ResourceID</Resource>
  <comments>
    <comment>comments1</comment>
    <comment>comments2</comment>
  </comments>
</root>
```